# Hyper-V Live migration without shared storage?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Hypothetical scenario:

- 2 machines running Hyper-V Server 2008 R2
- configured as a cluster
- VHD files stored on each machine

Is it possible to do a live migration without using shared storage? I imagine that it could take a very long time to copy the VHD files, but I want to know if Hyper-V has the intelligence to keep plugging along with a live migration that might last hours or days.

Comment: for production or for testing/demo purposes?

Comment: For production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, live migration requires shared storage (on both Hyper-V or VMware ESX) for Hyper V versions below 2012.

It is possible to do a live migration without shared storage on Hyper V with Server 2012's Shared Nothing functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 8 Server Hyper-V 3 has provided the "live migration without shared storage" feature. http://www.jamesbannanit.com/2012/03/windows-8-server-hyper-v-live-migration-without-shared-storage/

Answer (score 2):

KVM live migration has an option to enable block migration, which doesn't require the shared storage. Available starting from qemu-kvm-0.12

Comment: see also http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/KVM_Live_Block_Migration

Comment: How was this +4? The OP uses Hyper-V and this answer was for KVM? Wtf?